# Why do I have two GET variables with same name in url

Tags: php, html, forms, get

When I click submit button of form I get two variables with same name in url. Why this happens.

The form is following

```
<select name='name1' form='select_form'>...</select>
<select name='name2' form='select_form'>...</select>
<form id='select_form' action='index.php' method='get'>
<input type='text' name='date_start' value='val1' id='datepicker1'>
<input type='text' name='date_end' value='val2' id='datepicker2'>
<button id='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>Select</button>
</form>
```

When I click submit button I can see the following url

```
index.php?name1=val_name1&name2=val_name2&date_start=2016-08-01+00%3A00%3A00&date_start=&date_end=2016-08-03+00%3A00%3A00&date_end=2016-08-03+00%3A00%3A00
```

As you can see there are two date_start variables. What is the reason?
This has very bad impact, because when I change only one value (for example only date_start) then after clicking submit I have the following

```
index.php?name1=val_name1&name2=val_name2&date_start=2016-08-01+00%3A00%3A00&date_start=&date_end=2016-08-03+00%3A00%3A00&date_end=
```

So second value of date_end is empty.

Comment: Show your full form. Its possible you have something like `<form action='index.php?name1=val_name'>` so you get the first one from there.

Comment: <form action='index.php' id='select_form' method='get' style='width:100%'>
<div class='col-sm-2'><div class='dataTables_length' id='example_length'>
<label id='datepicker1_lbl'>From <input type='text' name='date_start' value='2016-08-01 00:00:00' id='datepicker1'></label></div></div>
<div class='col-sm-2'><div class='dataTables_length' id='example_length'><label id='datepicker2_lbl'>To <input type='text' name='date_end' value='2016-08-03 00:00:00' id='datepicker2'></label></div></div>

I have check in page source and there is only one name=date_start .

Comment: And there is some Javascript library operating the datepickers? Maybe that library is doing something weird.

Comment: Yes there is. I checked, on submit click the values are correct but when GET array is created there are two variables and one is empty. No idea what is the reason

Comment: Does it have the same issue with POST?

Comment: I'am trying it now, it will take some time to do all changes . If it works this will be workaround.

Comment: my guess at this point would be that the datepicker is adding a second hidden input with the same name...but if it doesn't happen with POST too, maybe its something else

Comment: The same is with POST ... How can I see hidden fields?

Comment: You can't I don't think. If Javascript is adding them, they won't be visible in view source. You need to look through the datepicker library code I guess (if its readable) or find a new datepicket library